# Automation of iOS configuration profile push

Tags: ios, mdm, configuration-profile

I have successfully set up a Mac mini server on the web with a static IP address and all to push configuration profiles to enrolled iOS devices using the Profile Manager. However, the use of profile manager uses a web interface which means that it can only be done manually.

However I have this scenario whereby I have a need to change the profile manager depending on the day. For example, iPhones camera are disabled on weekdays and enabled on weekends. As such, I am wondering if there is an API for me to interface with the Profile Manager programatically. A link to any form of documentation or any forum with such discussion would be extremely helpful as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ProfileManager is Ruby on Rails app running on OS X server. So, you can modify it's code to get behavior which you want. Sorry, I don't have more info on this, because  I have never played with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. At least I would have something to research on.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to solve this problem is to export the profile. Once you export the profile you will get a plist file with various keys. On the camera disabled profile, check out the keys that you have to modify and make that as a basic template.

Then write a code snippet that does the file edit operation. Check for the particular key_variable (eg:*allowCamera* ) and modify it according to your need. Run the code when you want to change the profile. Thus a new profile exactly like a template with little modification could be created.

Various variables are available under [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Dont think you can do it using profile manager. But if you use a MDM solution I think from time based policies you can achieve this.